# DataCompare on table without UniqueKey

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I was looking to use VS2010's data comparison tool but found out that it will not perform the comparison on a table without a unique key.  Is there a workaround for this while still using VS2010's data compare tool or another solution?

The end result I'm hoping to get is the delta of two tables that have the same schema but are in different databases.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best tools you can spend your money on: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/